# Allow power users on AWS to manage their passwords and keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created users with poweruser policy on AWS. The policy is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, following documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-credentials) I have create custom policy that should allow user to manage their own passwords and keys:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*LoginProfile",
                "iam:*AccessKey *",
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:*SSHPublicKey *"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListAccount*",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am still getting and error

> User: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/student is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateLoginProfile on resource: user student. Simulation gives explicit deny error, which is not the case according to these policies.

Comment: Did you attach the new policy to User "Student" in console?

Comment: Yes, I did. @error2007s

Comment: And did you verify if the student is power user?

Comment: Yes, I did. Student is part of the group called students. That group has two policies attached: 1.Custom policy that allows some IAM permissions. 2. PowerUserAccess (both policies attached in the question). Policies listed in that particular order. I have also tried to attach custom policy to the user directly but it has same problem. @error2007s

Comment: I replicated the same exact steps as above me too getting error I will dig deep and get back if I find any solution to this issue.

Comment: thanks.  @error2007s

Comment: In the above policy did you put your account number instead of "account-id-without-hyphens" and then attached it

Comment: Did you check my above comment?

Comment: Thats it, account number. It works now. Thank you so much for your help. I am still new to this. @error2007s

Comment: Can you mark my answer the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below in the code where it says `account-id-without-hyphens` replace that with your account number and it will work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*LoginProfile",
                "iam:*AccessKey *",
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:*SSHPublicKey *"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListAccount*",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```